# How do you find files that are not being used in Visual Studio 2012, and delete them

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Dropped a ton of files on a project, now I need to clean it up by deleting the files that are not being used. To optimize the app from loading all the necessary files.

I need to find and delete them. Thanks!

Comment: Would be nice if you can give some feedback to the answers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible without additional software. Some times ago a used [NDepend](http://ndepend.com/) (demo is available) for this job. Worked very well. I'm sure [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can also do it.

Answer (score 0):

You may just try parsing the csproj file as Xml to figure out what files are being used and cross check with files on the disk to get the list of files to be deleted.